# Debug in-app purchase outside of sandbox?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox

I have an app that uses non-consumable in-app purchases to provide content to the user.

These purchases work fantastically when I run from Xcode (via sandbox) or via ad-hoc builds (for some reason, also via sandbox). It's been approved by Apple and put on the AppStore. But when I download the production version from the store and click the "buy" button it fails.

Seeing as the problem only occurs in production, I'm a bit stymied as to how to debug it. I suspect it has something to do with purchasing through the sandbox vs. production servers, but even ad-hoc is done through the sandbox.

Is there anyway to debug this problem short of adding a bunch of alert dialogs and submitting to Apple again?

Comment: Did you ever find out what was wrong? I have the same problem.

Comment: I had contract amendments in iTunes Connect that I hadn't agreed to yet. About 15 minutes after approving the new amendments everything mysteriously started working. Don't know if that was the actual solution or not, but I do know new amendments just went out. Check your itunes connect to see if there's something new for you to approve?

Comment: Everything was right, but it took half a day after the app was approved until the store items were available it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are totally right;

You need all your Contracts (in iTunes Connect) to be active, otherwise you wont be able to make in-app purchases.

Comment: this does not really answer the question though. How to debug in-app purchases out of sandbox?